# Filtered Out String Still Causes Error in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am writing a part number generator app. Our part numbers consist of a nine digit numeric value, such as 914602001. Before creating a new number, there are several sources that need to be checked if it already exists. To try and save time, I've created a simple union of some of these sources. The union is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemNumber
FROM dbo.EngPartNumbers
WHERE (ItemNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ValueText COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ItemNumber
FROM [PDMWE-Bel-ArtProductsDocManagement].dbo.VariableValue AS vv
WHERE (ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') AND (LEN(ValueText) = 9)
```

The first table, *EngPartNumbers*, was an Excel file that was imported into SQL. It contains one column, ItemNumber, and is of varchar data type. It has to be varchar because there was a point in time where we used letters in our naming convention.

The second table is looking to our EPDM, where VariableValue is the table that stores all of the values to our variables, which is housed in the Variables table. The ValueText column is a varchar that holds all of the variable values. In my case, I'm only concerned about 9 digit numeric values, so I applied the last line:

```
WHERE (ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') AND (LEN(ValueText) = 9)
```

The results of the union is what I would expect; only numbers:

[image: Query results from vw_PDM_Union_Items]

This is where my problem is. Because I would like to get the next available number, I want to work with the int data type, not the varchar. When I select everything from my view, CAST the column as an int, and add a WHERE clause, like so:

```
SELECT ItemNumber 
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(ItemNumber AS int) AS ItemNumber 
    FROM vw_PDM_Union_Items
    ) AS x
WHERE ItemNumber < 800900000
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '"SW-Revision"' to data type int.

After research, I've noticed the "SW-Revision" refers to a value of a variable, which is stored in the ValueText column of the VariableValue table. To me, this shouldn't matter since I'm looking at my view which has already filtered out this bad data. I've even tried wrapping my view in a select statement that CASTs the column as an int, like so:

```
SELECT CAST(ItemNumber AS int) AS ItemNumber
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemNumber
      FROM dbo.EngPartNumbers
      WHERE (ItemNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT ValueText 
          COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ItemNumber
      FROM [PDMWE-Bel-ArtProductsDocManagement].dbo.VariableValue AS vv
      WHERE (ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') 
          AND (LEN(ValueText) = 9)) AS item
WHERE     (ItemNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

but I still get the same error. Why is SQL acting this way? What is happening in the background that causes it to look at the original table? If anyone can shed light on this situation and give me a better way to accomplish this, it would be appreciated. For manipulation sake, I would like to work with an int column, rather than a varchar.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate this error very easily

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  ValueText
            FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
            WHERE   t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        ) t
WHERE   ValueText < 10;
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

The reason is because regardless of whether you use a view, or just a normal query, you cannot control the order in which SQL Server applies the `WHERE` predicates.

Because of the error, we can't see what SQL server is doing by inspecting the execution plan, but a quick change to the query (SQL Server 2012+):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  ValueText
            FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
            WHERE   t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        ) t
WHERE   TRY_CONVERT(INT, ValueText) < 10;
```

Gives the following execution plan:

[image]

You can see, that SQL Server effectively simplifies the query this up to:

```
SELECT  ValueText
FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
WHERE   TRY_CONVERT(INT, ValueText) < 10;
AND     t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

It does the same with an implicit convert, so in the initial query you are just executing:

```
SELECT  ValueText
FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
WHERE   ValueText < 10;
AND     t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

Therefore, you get an error when evaluating `A < 10` since SQL Server tries to implicitly convert A to an integer in order to compare it with 10.

What you need to solve this is intermediate materialisation, that is to say, to force SQL Server to evaluate the subquery first, store the result, and then apply the outer predicates. This is easier said than done though. There is [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables) open to request this as a query hint, but, for now there are two main workarounds.

**1. Use a temporary table/table variable/Multi step TVF to materialise the results.**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ValueText INT)
INSERT @T (ValueText)
SELECT  ValueText
FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
WHERE   t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';

SELECT  *
FROM    @T
WHERE   ValueText < 10;
```

This is obviously not ideal for you since you want to use a view.

**2. Use `TOP 2147483647` (Massive Hack)**

```
SELECT  ValueText
FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 2147483647 ValueText
            FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
            WHERE   t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        ) t
WHERE   ValueText < 10;
```

It is a hack, and not guaranteed to work (although does in most cases I have had to use it), but using `TOP` and a number much bigger than you need will usually force the intermediate materialization of the results.

**3. Use a `CASE` expression to remove records**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  ValueText = CASE WHEN ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN ValueText END
            FROM    (VALUES ('A'), ('1')) t (ValueText)
            WHERE   t.ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        ) t
WHERE   ValueText < 10;
```

Again, this works, but I can't see that it would be guaranteed to work, there is no reason a future update would not recognise that the where predicate and the case predicate are the same and optimise the case expression away.

Comment: I was able to use Method 1 and add some lines to it to get what I needed. This will work great, and I appreciate you explaining everything thoroughly. Everyone else, I appreciate all of your replies and efforts in helping me with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bigint` or `decimal`:

```
SELECT ItemNumber 
FROM (SELECT CAST(ItemNumber AS decimal(38)) AS ItemNumber 
      FROM vw_PDM_Union_Items
     ) x
WHERE ItemNumber < 800900000;  -- large values are treated as numeric/decimal
```

EDIT:

You probably have values that are larger than expected as ItemNumber.  Does making the decimal size larger fix the problem?

You can check what the largest value is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber
FROM vw_PDM_Union_Items
ORDER BY LENGTH(ItemNumber) DESC, ItemNumber DESC;
```

I also note that you have a length restriction in the subquery.  Because of the way that SQL Server works, this may get invoked *after* attempting to convert the value.

You can enforce the order of evaluation by using `case`:

```
SELECT ItemNumber 
FROM (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN ItemNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                        THEN LEFT(ItemNumber, 9)
                   END) AS decimal(10)) AS ItemNumber
      FROM vw_PDM_Union_Items
     ) x
WHERE ItemNumber < 800900000;  -- large values are treated as numeric/decimal
```

I might suggest that you actually move this logic into the view.

Comment: I've tried a few different ideas, using the bigint and decimal, including your example, but continue to get this error: `Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.`

Comment: @GunnarHerman . . . SQL Server rearranges queries when optimizing them, so the conversion to a numeric value might occur *before* the filtering.  Microsoft considers this a *feature* because it enables certain optimizations.  See the edits on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now have reproduced it.

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT CAST(valuetext AS int)  AS ItemNumber
    FROM (
          select valuetext='SW-Revision' 
          union 
          select '123456789'
         ) AS vv
    WHERE (ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') 
) wrapper
where ItemNumber > 0;
```

I guess this is due to predicate pushing. As a workaround

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN valuetext NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN valuetext END AS int)  AS ItemNumber
    FROM (
          select valuetext='SW-Revision' 
          union 
          select '123456789'
         ) AS vv
    WHERE (ValueText NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') 
) wrapper
WHERE ItemNumber > 0
```

Comment: Essentially what you've created there is my view, which returns only numbers and filters out strings, which is great. If you wrap that in a select statement and add a `WHERE ItemNumber < 999999999', you get the error. This is the issue that I am having. If the view (or nested SQL statement in your case) is filtering out all alpha numeric rows, why do I get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if this would work...

```
SELECT ItemNumber 
FROM (
    SELECT case isnumeric(ItemNumber) 
        when 1 then CAST(ItemNumber AS int) 
        else -999999999
        end
        AS ItemNumber
    FROM vw_PDM_Union_Items
) AS x
WHERE ItemNumber < 800900000 
    and ItemNumber>-999999999
```